# Funny behavior from sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I have a piece of code below which basically reads a text file `data.txt` and prints to the console. The content of `data.txt` is below the code listing;

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 93

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    const char *datafile;
    char  line[BUFFER_SIZE],*string1;
    int a,b,c,d,e;

    FILE * File_ptr;

    datafile = "data.txt";
    File_ptr = fopen(datafile,"r");

    if(File_ptr == NULL ){
        printf("Error opening file %s\n",datafile);
    }

    while(fgets(line,BUFFER_SIZE,File_ptr) != 0){
        puts(line);
        sscanf(line, "%d %d %d %d %d %s", &a,&b,&c,&d,&e,string1);
        printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %s\n",a,b,c,d,e,string1);
    }

    fclose(File_ptr);
}
```

Content in `data.txt`:

```
100 200 888 456 5443 file1.abc
180 670 812 496 5993 file2.abc
160 230 345 546 5123 file3.abc
23 455 342 235 214 file4.abc
233 5455 3142 2435 1214 file5.abc
```

What I don't understand is: if the `BUFFER_SIZE` is defined as `< 97`, the output would be like this:

```
100 200 888 456 5443 file1.abc

100 200 888 456 5443 (null)
180 670 812 496 5993 file2.abc

180 670 812 496 5993 (null)
160 230 345 546 5123 file3.abc

160 230 345 546 5123 (null)
23 455 342 235 214 file4.abc

23 455 342 235 214 (null)
233 5455 3142 2435 1214 file5.abc

233 5455 3142 2435 1214 (null)
```

If the `BUFFER_SIZE` is defined as  `97 ~ 120`, the output would be OK, like this:

```
100 200 888 456 5443 file1.abc

100 200 888 456 5443 file1.abc
180 670 812 496 5993 file2.abc

180 670 812 496 5993 file2.abc
160 230 345 546 5123 file3.abc

160 230 345 546 5123 file3.abc
23 455 342 235 214 file4.abc

23 455 342 235 214 file4.abc
233 5455 3142 2435 1214 file5.abc

233 5455 3142 2435 1214 file5.abc
```

If the `BUFFER_SIZE` is defined as `>120`, a segmentation fault will be triggered at the `sscanf()` call.

Can someone enlighten me of the reason for this behavior?

Comment: regarding this code block beginning with:  'if(File_ptr == NULL ){'  when the variable File_ptr is NULL, then the program needs to report the error (I prefer using perror()) then exit the program, not fall through the end of the if code block and commence to trying to read from the file.

Comment: regarding this line: 'while(fgets(line,BUFFER_SIZE,File_ptr) != 0){'  fgets() returns a pointer, not a number.  the correct syntax would be: 'while(fgets(line,BUFFER_SIZE,File_ptr) != NULL){'

Comment: @user3629249: Formally both are correct. In pointer context (like this one) constant `0` is exactly equivalent to `NULL`. I prefer to use `NULL`, but some people prefer to use `0`. It is a matter of preference.

Answer (score 4):

Your `string1` is an uninitialized pointer that points nowhere. Your `sscanf` attempts to store data into the location pointed by `string1`, which is nowhere. Your program exhibits undefined behavior. It can segfault, it can output nonsense, it can do anything. The actual behavior of such program can change for no explainable reasons. This is exactly what you observe.